# Strange return value from Range.getValue() in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell formatted as time:

[image]

Executing this call:

```
Browser.msgBox(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getRange('F6').getValue());
```

results in:

[image]

What, on Earth, is going on??? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another much simpler solution is it to temporarily convert the format to string and then get the value:

```
function getValueAsText(range) {
  var oldFormat = range.getNumberFormat();
  range.setNumberFormat("@STRING@");
  var text = range.getValue();
  range.setNumberFormat(oldFormat);
  range.setValue(text);
  return text;
}

function testIt() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getRange('F6');
  Logger.log(getValueAsText(range));
}
```

Comment: This is really great. Thank you.

Comment: I found one small problem - with date cells, the value is lost. To overcome it, I set back the value with `range.setValue(text)` before returning the `text`.

Comment: Great, i've updated it in the code (oldValue will be backup value)

Comment: The funny thing is that it won't work this way. You have to set it with the text value. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You typed in .getStrange()... just kidding ;)
I had the same, but I only get 2 days before 1 Jan 1900. Did you also experiment with other times? I get this when typing 12:00:00

```
Sat Dec 30 1899 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

You can work around it by determining the compensation in milliseconds by this script:

```
function findDifferenceInTime() {
  var field = "A2";
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(field);
  var oldValue = range.getValue(), oldFormat = range.getNumberFormat();
  range.setNumberFormat("H:mm:ss");
  range.setValue(0);
  var value = range.getValue();
  range.setValue(oldValue);
  range.setNumberFormat(oldFormat);
  Logger.log("The time 0:00:00 will be represented as: " + - new Date(value).getTime());
  return - new Date(value).getTime();
}
```

And then correct this with this script (that's how I worked around it hacky-style)

```
function test() {
  Logger.log(displayTime(getTime("A2")));
}

function getTime(range) {
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getValue();
  var beginningOfTimes = findDifferenceInTime();
  var milliseconds = new Date(value).getTime() + beginningOfTimes;
  return milliseconds;
}

function displayTime(milliseconds) {
    var h = Math.floor(milliseconds/(60*60*1000));
    var m = (Math.floor(milliseconds/(60*1000))) % 60;
    var s = (Math.floor(milliseconds/1000)) % 60;
    return showTwoDigits(h) + ":" + showTwoDigits(m) + ":" + showTwoDigits(s);
}

function showTwoDigits(number) {
    return ("00" + number).slice(-2);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you time! Uau! This is quite complicate :) Isn't there a `Range.getValueAsText()` function which will return whatever is displayed as text?!

Comment: No because its not text. its a date. the code here is more complex than it needs to be. the actual issue is that your timezone (both spreadsheet and script have timezone properties) might be incorrectly set. else you can use other more standard js ways to convert timezones.

Comment: You can write a getValueAsText function, see next post.

Comment: @ZigMandel of course it is not text. If it were text, I would just take its value. I am asking - isn't there a built-in function to take a cell value as text?

Comment: I actually find the ultimate solution, I will post it :)

Answer (score 0):

I belief the ultimate solution to this is that the timezone set in the spreadsheet (menu file -> spreadsheet preferences) and the timezone set in the script editor (menu File -> Project properties) must be the same. If you have for example timezone 1:00 Paris and 1:00 Berlin then you will even get strange results. You also need to format the date to the correct timezone again in the script:

```
function showCorrectTime() {
  var range = 'F6';
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getValue()
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(value, Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'hh:mm:ss'));
}
```